# USA stamping passport inconsistently

Tags: usa, passport-stamps, cbp

I am a US citizen.  2013 to 2018, I left USA and returned many times.  Looking through my passport now, I see that only about half the entries were stamped.  I don't recall any significant differences to explain it.

Are there any CBP rules or even customary practices to explain the inconsistency?

Comment: Do you use the Global Entry machines? I've traveled a lot in the last ten years, and have no US entry stamps in my US passport from those GE interactions.

Comment: Only once—because it took longer than going through the queue!